# Subspace complementary to countable many subspaces.

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ of dimension $n$ and $V_i$, $i\in{\Bbb{N}}$ are countable many subspaces of dimension $k$. I would like to prove then that there is a constant subspace $W$ such that  $$V=W\oplus{V_i}$$ for every $i\in{\Bbb{N}}.$ I can prove the case with $k=1$ finding a vector that does not belong to the $V_i$ $\forall{i\in{\Bbb{N}}}$. 
For example if $dimV=3$ and $dimV_i=2$,with $V_i=<(x_1^{i},x_2^{i},x_3^{i}),(y_1^{i},y_2^{i},y_3^{i}))>,i\in{\Bbb{N}}$  and $b\neq{\begin{vmatrix}
   x_2^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_2^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}\over\begin{vmatrix}
     x_1^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_1^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}$
   , whenever ${\begin{vmatrix}
     x_1^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_1^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}\neq0$ and  $a\neq{b{\begin{vmatrix}
   x_1^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_1^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}\over\begin{vmatrix}
     x_2^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_2^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}-{{\begin{vmatrix}
   x_1^{i} & x_2^{i}\\
    y_1^{i} & y_2^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}\over\begin{vmatrix}
     x_2^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_2^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}}$,  whenever ${\begin{vmatrix}
     x_2^{i} & x_3^{i}\\
    y_2^{i} & y_3^{i}\\
    \end{vmatrix}}\neq0$. Then ${
    \begin{vmatrix}
   x_1^{i} & x_2^{i} & x_3^{i} \\
   y_1^{i} & y_2^{i} & y_3^{i} \\
    a & b & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}\neq0}$ for every $i\in{\Bbb{N}}$ and the subspace $W=<(a,b,1)>$ is what we need. 
The thing is, I cannot proceed with the general case for $k$ and $n$...Any hint please?